# Add-Migration generates different migrations in VS2017 vs. VS2015

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-6

We recently moved from VS2015 to VS2017 for our EF Code First application.  Some of the developers on the team (but not all) get different results calling Add-Migration on VS2015 and VS2017.

For instance, if I generate a migration on VS2015 with no outstanding model changes and a fresh build I get the expected empty migration

```
Add-Migration ... -Name ShouldBeAnEmptyMigration
```

gives me:

```
namespace Blah.Foo.DataModel.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class ShouldBeAnEmptyMigration: DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

If I roll those changes back and run the same command against the same database from VS2017 I get a migration full of unwanted changes:

```
namespace Blah.Foo.DataModel.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class ShouldBeAnEmptyMigration: DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            // For some reason EF is trying to add foreign key columns that
            // already exist except with an additional suffix of "1".
            // e.g. We already have an FK from 'Child' to 'Parent' using
            // Guid Parent_Id which has been in place for (literally) years.
            // There are 11 such columns it is trying to add here.
            // Some date base a couple years, some are more recent.
            // I don't see a pattern for which columns it is choosing

            // 11 of these, one for each "new" column ...
            DropForeignKey("Child", "Parent_Id", "Parent");
            ...
            // 11 of these ...
            DropIndex("Child", new[] { "Parent_Id" });
            ...
            // 11 of these ...
            AddColumn("Child", "Parent_Id1", c => c.Guid(nullable: false));
            ...
            // 11 of these ...
            CreateIndex("Child", "Parent_Id1");
            ...
            // 11 of these ...
            AddForeignKey("Child", "Parent_Id1", "Parent", "Id");
            ...
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            // similar set of DropForeignKey, DropIndex, DropColumn,
            // CreateIndex, AddForeignKey
        }
    }
}
```

Note that there are no recent changes to most of the DataModels affected.

Currently I am forced to create all my migrations on VS2015.  Is there any way to make VS2017 "behave"?

### Versions:

- Visual Studio Pro 2015 (14.0.25431.01 Update 3)
- Visual Studio Pro 2017 (15.9.7)
- EntityFramework.6.2.0